# Are entire websites automatically cached (Google using <style>)?

Tags: css, caching, http-caching

I've heard of **stylesheets** being cached, but are regular pages (like the one we're on) cached? I noticed on the more recent websites Google has made, they are not even using stylesheets, just a `<style>` tag with a single, compressed line of CSS. This led me to believe that the entire page (including the `<style>`) is cached, and not just stylesheets. Am I correct on this? Why would Google not use stylesheets and want their CSS to be cached when their sites are viewed billions of times a month.

From my understanding, everything that appears in the "Network Panel" of Chrome's inspect element is cached?

I researched "PHP Caching" but that seems to be for `include`'s, so I'm guessing pages are already cached automatically.

Comment: You need to learn about HTTP caching headers.

Comment: Take a look at [Nginx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx)

Comment: Google is far far beyond the problem of caching their files. They won't even use HTTP if you use their browser and/or OS (they may use SPDY). They're doing hundreds of A/B testing at once. Serving logged users for dozens of services around the world. For any of us that'd be overoptimizing. Don't try to mimick one feature you saw on one of their sites, there are probably dozens of factors that lead them to its use that we ignore, and years of experience. Google Page Speed and YSlow! are good enough for most projects. Then you can read what Steve Souders and others write on the subject.

Comment: @FelipeAls thanks, I won't, I was just curious as to their odd techniques throughout their websites :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this post: [CACHING TUTORIAL](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/).

Use `<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">` tag in your `<head/>` section.
Use [headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) in your PHP code:

```
<?php
 Header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
 $offset = 60 * 60 * 24 * 3;
 $ExpStr = "Expires: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $offset) . " GMT";
 Header($ExpStr);
?>
```

Comment: Ah I see. I always used no-cache for development. Why would google not use a stylesheet across all their websites though?

Comment: @ArthurHamla: Could you summarize the important content in that link?

Comment: Google cache whole pages using something like Nginx server. Also thay have CDN servers etc. You can pass headers (using your web server) to ask user client make local cach of your page for some time. Or you can put relevant meta tag to your HTML markup. There are a lot of posible methods doing this.

Comment: @Adam184 Google probably do share a stylesheet across multiple websites, but they've decided for some to inline it to reduce the number of requests and speed up the page load

Comment: @AndyDavies Thanks :) Some of Google's practices seem unstandarized, for instance about a month ago, their main google search page used three <table>s for a single search bar. I'm not sure whether they were trying to be mischievous or if there is actually a reason lol. And on some pages, they put all the <head> stuff in the <body> tag... but I've decided... who cares?!?! lol

Comment: They are constantly running experiments. Optimisations that work for them and other large sites may not work for everyone else of course

Answer (score 1):

Caching is about resources corresponding to individual URLs, not about sites. Basically, resources of all kinds, like HTML documents, images, style sheets, JavaScript code, plain texts etc. etc. can be cached. So a site as an entity is not cached, and neither is a “whole page” (HTML document + images used in it + stylesheets it refers to +...). But each component may be cached, under its own URL.

Google uses embedded `style` elements for some very short style sheets, probably because they think this is more efficient than using an external CSS file. The HTML document may well be cached, but even if it is not, their approach is a little bit faster than using an external style sheet, which may cause HTTP overhead.

But for any nontrivial CSS code that you use on different pages of your site, an external CSS file is more efficient. It will be loaded (with small HTTP overhead) when a user first visits your site, but when he moves around it, the browser will have the CSS code in its own cache.